# fetch isn't working for images on my node.js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Can't seem to figure this out. I'm trying to read in an image URL to convert to blob and then to base 64. The fetch however is working for random images I got on the web but not from my node express server. This is working:

```
const temp1 = await fetch('https://i.imgur.com/gBi0yjr.png')
OR
const temp1 = await fetch('https://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/trinidadexpress.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/6/a9/6a9c60aa-fd6f-11ed-87be-3bf93ae39a75/6473785904acb.image.jpg?resize=889%2C500')
```

The fetch is reading in the image URL properly and converting to base64. However when I use my node server as follows:

```
const temp1 = await fetch('https://filmreviewsnode.herokuapp.com/images/1.jpg')
```

I"m getting the following error

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at test (use-InputValidator.js:67:1)
    at changeHandler (use-InputValidator.js:39:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
```

I think this has something to do with node express but can't figure it out. I made my /images folder accessible as follows in node.js:

**app.js**

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});
```

And you could see if you open`https://filmreviewsnode.herokuapp.com/images/1.jpg` in your browser you'll access the image. However for some reason it's giving trouble with `fetch` in react. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use the npm package Cors?

Comment: Look in the network tab and see what url the browser is trying to use to download your images and also what error the server is returning.

Comment: @D. who owns the `https://filmreviewsnode.herokuapp.com`? It's blocked by CORS you need to set it up to relax the browser's same-origin policy.

Comment: @Wahlstrommm  it's working now, I installed `npm i cors` and included this in `app.js`:        `app.use(cors());  `  However isnt this line in my app.js above handling cors?: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`